# How to close a dropDown div on clicking on one of the <li> inside it or outside the div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a burger icon that show on small screens, on clicking on it a div is shown beneath the navigation menu containing some `<li>` elements that are used for navigation among pages .

```
<div class='tabs'>
    <ul class="navs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Organizations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><input type="text" class="search-input"><button type="submit" class="search-button"><img src=""/></button></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

The burger icon :

```
<label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"></input>
```

When I click the burger icon the dropdown menu appears and if I click on one of the `<li>`, `active` class is added to this `<li>`

I want to close this dropdown after clicking on one of the `<li>` or click outside the `tabs` div using Javascript .

**I'm not using Bootstrap or Jquery.**

Comment: Please share what you have tried and any errors that you are receiving. [ask]

Comment: I haven't tried because i'm not sure how it could be done

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions here, if you add jQuery or if you want raw JavaScript:

```
// jQuery version
let toggle = $('#toggle');
let menu = $('.navs');

toggle.click(() => {
  menu.toggleClass('active');
});


// non-jQuery / raw JavaScript 
let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
let menu = document.getElementsByClassName('navs');

toggle.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

You may have to tweak a little bit to your page.  `element.classList` is standard now, that said some older browsers may not support it.

Comment: I don't want to add "active" class , I already did that , I want to close the "navs" div in clicking on one of the lis or outside the "navs" div

Comment: Sure, you just need to use a different css class to control the show/hide.  Doesn't have to be "active".  You can also set the display:none display:block property manually, but I would not recommend going that route.